# Sending data between activities simultaneously whilst data is updated constantly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically, I am receiving external sensor data from a Firebase Realtime Database. What I am trying to do is send that data from my main activity to another activity simultaneously.

I tried using shared preferences but it only updates once after a button click, what I want is that the second activity should receive the changes which are updating in the main activity.

**Main Activity Code:**

```
 reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String s1=dataSnapshot.child("sensor1").getValue().toString();
                String s2=dataSnapshot.child("sensor2").getValue().toString();
                et1.setText(s1);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                editor.putString("sensor1data",s1);
                editor.apply();
```

**Second Activity Code;**

```
   sp=getSharedPreferences("s",MODE_PRIVATE);

        cc=sp.getString("sensor1data","");
        tv.setText(cc);
```

and `SharedPreferences sp;` is declared globally in both the activities

I also tried adding a listener but to no available, kept getting an error whenever using this line:

```
sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

the error for above line:

```
registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener cannot be applied to (android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener) in **SharedPreferences** cannot be applied to (com.example.s1.MainActivity)
```

I also tried it this way but also got an error in the second line where it said cannot resolve symbol `sharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the second line.

```
    SharedPreferences spla=this.getSharedPreferences("s",MODE_PRIVATE);
spla.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(`sharedPreferenceChangeListener`);

SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener sharedPreferenceChangeListner =new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Do you need to store this data? If not why don't you use an interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I want is that the second activity should receive the changes which are updating in the main activity.

While there are some workarounds that can help you send data from an activity to another once the operation of getting data is complete, the simplest solution is to attach a listener directly in the second activity. In this way, you are notified in real-time about every change that takes place on Firebase servers.